# Block visitors access to specific folder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a folder called "Config". Config folder have all config xml files.

I can block visitors access to Config folder in asp.net?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of IIS? It may just be simpler to make an IIS change instead.

Comment: my version off IIS is 7.5, but if i use IIS to block folder, changes arent lost when i upload it to hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "Config XML" files have a `.config` extension, there is no need to block access. The ASP.Net engine does not serve `.config` files. Your users would not be able to access them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Put this web.config file in the config folder. Please note, your application will not be able to read any files from that folder. Probably you would want to allow authenticated users only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

That is what you will get if you try to access any file inside the config folder[image]

Comment: inside /Config right? i put it but nothing happens, i can access to the file

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the authentication set in IIS for that application?

Comment: anonymous : enabled, forms : disabled, asp impersonation : disabled

Comment: Its the same setting as I have. Can you try it first on localhost?

Comment: i tested in localhost/ and works, but shows xml data in localhost/Config/global.xml

Comment: I cannot think of anything else. Can you post your web.config from the root level?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a web.config? Add a web.config file to your folder and restrict access to all users:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For IIS 7 try:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I copied your code to /Config but i can enter to the xml http://website.com/Config/global.xml

Comment: can you store your config files in the App_Data folder? IIS disallows access to it

Comment: I did not know that! I can do it,thanks for the info. Anyway I would want to know why Web.Config does not works.

Comment: what version of IIS are you using?